# Pre-loader loads behind block content and navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a preloader which is loading in front of the `<body>` but not in front of the site `<navbar>` or the `{% block content %}`. `#preloader{z-index:999;}`

- Django 2.2.7
- Bootstrap 4.4.1
- JQuery 3.4.1

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#preloader').addClass('loaded');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#preloader').addClass("notta");
}, 2000);
});
```

```css
#preloader:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#preloader.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in 1s;
}
#preloader.notta {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="flex-center" id="preloader">
    <div class="preloader-wrapper active">
        <div class="spinner-grow text-warning" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

If I put the preloader at the bottom of the `<body>` it will load on top of the `{% block content %}` but underneath the navbar. I assume this means it has to do with the order of loading?

How do I get it to show up *above* **everything** on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem come here from your `:before` element in css. Just combine it with `#preloader`:

```js
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#preloader').addClass('loaded');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#preloader').addClass("notta");
    }, 2000);
  });
```

```css
#preloader {
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

#preloader.loaded {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in 1s;
}

#preloader.notta {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<header>
  <div class="flex-center" id="preloader">
    <div class="preloader-wrapper active">
      <div class="spinner-grow text-warning" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code with pure Javascript

```
`let loader = document.getElementById('preloader');
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
loader.style.display = 'none';
});`
```

Try this

Comment: I like the idea of vanilla JS but I already have a bit of both JQuery and JS in my project so it isn't a big deal. I am normally focused on the back-end (Python/Django). Would you mind telling me what the benefit of using vanilla JS would be?

Comment: That's true but definitively not answer the question. Please move this `comment` to the right section an `delete` this post ;)